# Microsoft 365 Can't add multiple groups to CA policies through PowerShell Function

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

Hi first time posting here, I'm trying to create some modules for my company for easier Microsoft 365 Management and automating tenant creation. I've run into a bit of an issue when trying to create a new conditional access policy with multiple groups assigned to it. Here is my code:

```
function New-MFACAPolicy {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Groups,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet('enabled', 'enabledForReportingButNotEnforced', 'disabled')]
        [string]$State,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$ExcludedGroups
    )

    BEGIN{
        Test-AzureADConnection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        #Create Empty Array
        $IncludedGroups = @()
        $ExclGroups = @()
        #Loop through Groups listed and add to array of Object ID's for each group
        foreach ($Group in $Groups) {

            $IncludedGroup = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString $Group

            $IncludedGroups += $IncludedGroup.id
            
        }#Foreach

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ExcludedGroups')) {

            foreach ($ExcludedGroup in $ExcludedGroups) {
                
                $ExclGroup = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString $ExcludedGroup

                $ExclGroups += $ExclGroup.id 

            }#Foreach
            
        }#If Excluded Groups parameter is specified

        $InclGroups = $($IncludedGroups -join ', ')

    }#Begin

    Process {

    $Conditions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessConditionSet
    $Conditions.Applications = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessApplicationCondition
    $Conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = "All"
    $Conditions.Users = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessUserCondition
    $conditions.Users.IncludeGroups = "$InclGroups"
    $Conditions.ClientAppTypes = @('Browser','MobileAppsAndDesktopClients')
    $Controls = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessGrantControls
    $controls._Operator = "OR"
    $Controls.BuiltInControls = "mfa"

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ExcludedGroups')) {

            $Conditions.Users.ExcludeGroups = "$ExcludedGroups"
        
        }#If ExlcudedGroups parameter specified 

    New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName "CA001: Require MFA for all Licensed Users" -State $State -Conditions $Conditions -GrantControls $Controls
    }#Process
}
```

Not sure why but I can add a single group just fine when running NewMFACAPolicy -Groups "HR" -State enabledForReportingButNotEnforced

but when specifying multiple groups NewMFACAPolicy -Groups "HR", "Marketing" -State enabledForReportingButNotEnforced I receive the following error message:

```
New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy
Code: BadRequest
Message: 1054: Invalid group value: GroupID1, GroupID2. <--- This is usually the ID of the group I redacted it to hide that information
InnerError:
  RequestId: 53f15e3e-53cc-4c10-a537-983b8d6f87a6
  DateTimeStamp: Thu, 28 Oct 2021 14:21:42 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest
HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At C:\Users\Redacted\New-CAPolicies.ps1:63 char:5
+     New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName "CA001: Require ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.PowerShell.NewAz
   ureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy
```

Not sure why this won't work as I'm just turning an array into a comma separated string... If there is a better way to do this that someone can suggest I'm definitely open to redoing this.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to remove the quotes and keep it an array.

Final version:

```
    function New-MFACAPolicy {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position = 0)]
        [string[]]$Groups,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateSet('enabled', 'enabledForReportingButNotEnforced', 'disabled')]
        [string]$State,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$ExcludedGroups
    )

    BEGIN{
        Test-AzureADConnection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        #Create Empty Array
        $IncludedGroups = @()
        $ExclGroups = @()
        #Loop through Groups listed and add to array of Object ID's for each group
        foreach ($Group in $Groups) {

            $IncludedGroup = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString $Group

            $IncludedGroups += $IncludedGroup.id
            
        }#Foreach

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ExcludedGroups')) {

            foreach ($ExcludedGroup in $ExcludedGroups) {
                
                $ExclGroup = Get-AzureADMSGroup -SearchString $ExcludedGroup

                $ExclGroups += $ExclGroup.id 

            }#Foreach
            
        }#If Excluded Groups parameter is specified
        
    }#Begin

    Process {

    $Conditions = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessConditionSet
    $Conditions.Applications = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessApplicationCondition
    $Conditions.Applications.IncludeApplications = "All"
    $Conditions.Users = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessUserCondition
    $conditions.Users.IncludeGroups = $IncludedGroups
    $Conditions.ClientAppTypes = @('Browser','MobileAppsAndDesktopClients')
    $Controls = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.MSGraph.Model.ConditionalAccessGrantControls
    $controls._Operator = "OR"
    $Controls.BuiltInControls = "mfa"

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ExcludedGroups')) {

            $Conditions.Users.ExcludeGroups = $ExclGroups
        
        }#If ExlcudedGroups parameter specified 

    New-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy -DisplayName "CA001: Require MFA for all Licensed Users" -State $State -Conditions $Conditions -GrantControls $Controls
    }#Process
}#Function
```